# What does %-mark mean in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've tried to find the answer but it's quite difficult to search just the %-mark. So I've seen %-mark sometimes but I can't understand what is its function. It would be very nice if somebody could tell the explanation.

Comment: more clojure symbols that are hard to google - http://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#(blah %)` is shorthand for an argument to an anonymous function.  So if you're squaring each element in a list, instead of

```
(map (fn [x] (* x x)) [1 2 3])
```

you can write

```
(map #(* % %) [1 2 3])
```

i.e. substituting `#(* % %)` for `(fn [x] (* x x))` as the anonymous function.  Each will give `(1 4 9)`

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is inside an anonymous function, like `#(first %)` if so it means the first parameter. If there are more that one, you can number them `%1`,`%2` etc.

So for instance

`(filter #(odd? %) [1 2 3 4 5 6]) => (1 3 5)`

Note: In this example you would normally just do `(filter odd? [1 2 3 4 5 6])`

Comment: Okay, thanks. And is it same than to write (filter (fn [x] (odd? x)) [1 2 3 4 5 6])?

Comment: Yes, `#(..)` is a reader macro that is transformed into (fn [] ..). For example: `(read-string "#(+ 1 %)") => (fn* [p1__40420#] (+ 1 p1__40420#))`. Check out http://clojure.org/reader to learn more about the reader.

Answer (score 1):

% is just a placeholder for arguments in the #(...) reader macro witch rewrites to a (fn* ...) call. It means the first passed argument.

You can add a number after the % to indicate index number of argument, beware first argument index is 1, so % == %1.

You shall provide as many arguments to the returned function as the highest index you use in the function definition.

```
#(str %4 %2)
```

gives

```
(fn* [p1__680# p2__679# p3__681# p4__678#] (str p4__678# p2__679#))
```

and needs 4 arguments.

Observe that %4 and %2 are managed first and in reading order and non used arguments are created after by the macro filling the gaps.